# React Fetch Throw Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

react newbie here. I was using the react fetch api and came across an issue when trying to throw a custom error. I have a rest api endpoint running on localhost:8080. I have since turned off the process (mimicking a down service) I want to throw a more descriptive error rather than the standard "Failed to Fetch" error. It seems the code is rejecting my error above and using the default fetch error. Is there a way to override this?

```
fetchData() {
fetch('http://localhost:8080/locales/all')
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw Error('Oops, looks like the service is down :-(');
  })
  .then(parsedJSON => {
    this.setState({
      locales: parsedJSON.content,
      isLoading:false
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    this.setState({
      error: error.message,
      isLoading:false
    });
    console.log(error.message); // results in Failed to fetch
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's `fetch` itself is failing, not even getting to `then`? Possibly because IIRC there's an issue with using `localhost` (you have to do some permission stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the initial `fetch` call *may* resolve with a `Response` object, but if the `fetch` fails completely, it will not resolve at all, and will proceed directly to the `catch`. This will be clear if you put this in your code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/locales/all')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('got a response');
```

When you don't see `got a response`, you won't be able to `throw` the custom error message inside the `.then`.

```js
function fetchData() {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/locales/all')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('got a response');
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error('Oops, looks like the service is down :-(');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
fetchData();
```

Rather, you might change the error message inside the `catch` itself:

```
}).catch(error => {
  if (error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
    // change the message, or handle as needed:
    error.message = 'Oops, looks like the service is down :-(';
  }
```

```js
function fetchData() {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/locales/all')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('got a response');
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error('Oops, looks like the service is down :-(');
    }).catch(error => {
      if (error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
        error.message = 'Oops, looks like the service is down :-(';
      }
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
fetchData();
```

Comment: That's exactly it! It never gets a response and goes straight to the catch. Thank you for the help much appreciated.